# iteration over enum in ruby

Tags: ruby, enums

i have the following ruby class (user.rd) that has an enum (UserStatus):

```
class User< ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UserStatus
  NEW = "new"
  OLD = "old"
  DELETED = "deleted"
end
```

is there a way i can iterate over all the enum values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have created there are called 'constants', not enumerations. As Zabba said, *"Ruby does not have 'enum'."* If you must keep this data structure, if you are already using the constants in your code, then you can iterate them like so:

```
UserStatus.constants(false).each do |const_name|
  p [ const_name, UserStatus.const_get( const_name ) ]
end
#=> :NEW, "new"]
#=> [:OLD, "old"]
#=> [:DELETED, "deleted"]
```

The use of `false` above is needed to prevent you from getting constants defined in superclasses:

```
class Foo; A = 1; end
class Bar < Foo; B = 1; end

Bar.constants
#=> [:B, :A]
Bar.constants(false)
#=> [:B]
```

If you are not married to the use of individual constants, you might be interested in creating a frozen Hash of immutable values instead:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  STATUS = {
    :new => 'new',
    :old => 'old',
    :deleted => 'deleted'
  }
  STATUS.freeze
  STATUS.values.each{ |v| v.freeze }
end

bob.status = User::STATUS[:new]
User::STATUS.each do |name,string|
  p [ name, string ]
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Ruby does not have "enum". Those are constants that you have defined.
Given that, you can iterate over constants in a class like this:

```
#UserStatus.constants returns an array, which we then iterate over
UserStatus.constants.each do |el|
  p el
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?id=184 (slight improvement over http://www.rubyfleebie.com/enumerations-and-ruby/). Lets you write the following.

```
class Gender
  include Enum

  Gender.define :MALE, "male"
  Gender.define :FEMALE, "female"
end
```

And of course

```
Gender.all
Gender::MALE
```